# Ways to Change IPC 4761 Via Type in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, power-electronics, altium

I would like to change the via type in Altium Designer in the IPC 4761 section. However, Altium Designer is not allowing me to change it. Is there any way to change it?

[image]

Moreover, if I would like to use via under pad or outside the pad in the trace should it be filled? What type should I use then?

[image: Via Under Pad--Filled Via?]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this.  After selecting IPC-4761 on one via type, a new layer appeared called "Filling" set to Layer Type "Filling" if you right click the layer and "edit" under Mechanical Layers.  This then creates a new via template in the template list (appending "(1)" to the previous selected via template.  Selecting other vias, whether different blind or not, and using the same template, you can get the filling layer to show on those vias as well.  Exporting via ODB++ (make sure to tick the extra rows that now exist for these new layer outputs).  Probably a way to go make via templates directly with the filling layer selected and IPC type chosen.